# SQL command not properly ended SELECT-Statement in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, recordset

I think I'm at a loss here. I'm trying to open a recordset with the given SQL-String, but all I get is an Error ORA-00933 SQL Command not properly ended.

I already tried to circle in the error and it seems I made a mistake in the WHERE-clause, but I'm kinda stuck and don't get it where the mistake's at.

```
strsql = "SELECT QSYS.DOKUMENTE.SDATEINAME 
          FROM QSYS.DOKUMENTE 
          INNER JOIN QSYS.RQMS_STAMM 
              ON QSYS.DOKUMENTE.NLFD = QSYS.RQMS_STAMM.NRQNR"
& _      "WHERE QSYS.DOKUMENTE.NLFD = QSYS.RQMS_STAMM.NRQNR
              AND QSYS.RMQS_STAMM.SRQNR = '"& Me.lstReklamenummern.Value &"'" 
objrcrd.Open strsql
```

Comment: Firstly, I think you seem needing to leave a space after  `..On QSYS.DOKUMENTE.NLFD = QSYS.RQMS_STAMM.NRQNR"`, and make sure that `&Me.lstReklamenummern.Value` is not null.

Comment: well... the space it was! Thanks. 
Damn hide and seek. :^)

Comment: You are missing a space before the `Where`. It's easy to see such errors when you put a statement `Debug.Print strsql` before you issue the command

Comment: you're welcome :)